# How to write arrays to tab delimited text file?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays -

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2};
int[] array2 = { 6, 7};
```

I want to write them in text file delimited by tab.

Final Result -

1 6
2 7

Please suggest how to do this?

Comment: Well, which bit of it is causing you problems? Do you know how to write text files? Will there only ever be two arrays?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Have you looked at the documentation on how to write to files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public void writeFile(int[] array){
         using (streamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true){
              for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++){
                   sw.WriteLine(array[i] + "\t");
              }
         }
    }
```

Then you would just call the write method like this: 
`writeFile(array1);
writeFile(array2);`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to use using clause. Now it's working. As suggested /t instead of " "

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arrays are of the same length:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename,
    Enumerable.Range(0, arr1.Length)
              .Select(i => string.Format("{0}\t{1}", arr1[i], arr2[i]));
```

Comment: Enumerable.Zip looks cooler for such question and additionally takes care of mismatched array length.